# WCF Data Services Client: How to select matching entities based on a provided T generic type and a Func?

Tags: c#, linq, wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-data-services-client

I'm using the WCF Data Services/Odata client library, and if I target the Northwind sample OData store at http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/ , with the following instruction I can retrieve the products which have a quantity bigger than 50:

```
var r = context.Products.Where(w=> w.UnitsInStock > 50)
```

My question is, suppose I want to have a generic class which must perform this operation, but instead of hardcoding the entity to retrieve (Products in this case) and the condition over the same entity (UnitsInStock > 50), I would want to supply the entity object/name and the condition as a Func. What I would like was to have something like the following class, where the imaginary ***GetEntityType*** function would infere the entity from the supplied T, but unfortunatelly GetEntityType does not exist and I haven't found how to accomplish the same task:

```
public class OdataTesting<T>
{
    ...
    public IQueryable<T> ReturnItem(Func<T, bool> selector)
    {
        return context.GetEntityType<T>().Where(w=> selector(w));
    }
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I've found the CreateQuery method, which can be used as follows:

```
return context.CreateQuery<T>("Products").Where(w=> selector(w));
```

But...
1. I can't find a way to get the string entity name associated to a data type. Is there a way to get it programatically from T?
2. The URI generator seems to have dificulties when functions are used to filter the entities, so I'll have to investigate further for alternatives. Sugestions are welcome

**UPDATE 2:**
The entity string name can be retrieved using reflection:

```
string s = ((global::System.Data.Services.Common.EntitySetAttribute)(typeof(Product).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(global::System.Data.Services.Common.EntitySetAttribute), true)[0])).EntitySet;
```

If there is another more recomnended way to do it, please share.

I'm still looking for a way to dinamically provide the condition to retrieve the entities from the service.

Comment: That's not hard-coded, that's called your model. If you can work around it, it would be more inconvenient than the so-called `hard-coded`.

Comment: I can't help but feel like you're over thinking this. Its like you're abstracting where, which is already generic and accepts a predicate.